# How to Reverse a Migration that Requires a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-migrations

I recently tested the [Queue_Classic](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic) gem in my app. Part of the setup is running this migration:

```
require 'queue_classic'

class AddQueueClassic < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    QC::Setup.create
  end

  def self.down
    QC::Setup.drop
  end
end
```

Now I'd like to switch to a different queueing system, but I'm afraid that I won't be able to remove queue_classic from the Gemfile. Even if I generate a migration that just runs:

```
drop_table :queue_classic_jobs
```

Won't `rake db:migrate` still complain when it sees the first instance of `require 'queue_classic'` and `QC::Setup.create` but can't find the queue_classic gem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with editing or deleting old migrations, they're meant to be temporary helpers, they're not a permanent part of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the migration to do `QC::Setup.drop` and run it.

Then delete the original `AddQueueClassic` migration altogether.

Comment: Good enough. Any danger in deleting the original (and new) migration?

Comment: Not if you've removed the Gem and that is the only dependency.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, that is true. that's the case why, at some point, you just get rid of old migrations and use the schema.rb http://adventuresincoding.com/2010/02/how-to-clean-up-your-activerecord-migrations